# Need Help 'MemoryRouter' is not exported from 'react-router'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i have a problem.

After create new react app i see this problem in my old project

./node_modules/react-router-dom/esm/react-router-dom.js
Attempted import error: 'MemoryRouter' is not exported from 'react-router'.

I use this in my project

import {
BrowserRouter, Router,
} from "react-router-dom";

Please i need help : )

Comment: Have you installed package via npm, if not in your main directory in command prompt run ```npm install react-router-dom```

Comment: that dont work : (

Comment: maybe problem in package.json ?

  "react-jquery-plugin": "^1.1.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "react-router": "^3.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "use-sound": "^2.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"

Comment: AS mentioned before, you may want to try and import `Route` not `Router` and verify that your package.json contains `react-router-dom` in the `dependencies` list. Finally don't forget to install `node_modules` by running `npm install` or `yarn` If you are using yarn.

Comment: there is a mismatch in react-router-dom and react-router  change react-router to 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Ther is a mismatch in packages , try update package.json to below versions and do npm install to update packages

```
"react-router": "^5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
```